# Google Drive: share a folder which is not in the root

Tags: file-sharing, google-drive

Is there a way for sharing a folder on Google Drive without having it in the root of Google Drive?

If not possible:

1. Do you know a sharing system with a decent free size, that allows this option?
2. The other way around, is it possible to exclude sub-folders from the sharing?

N.B. For sharing I mean uploading it online, not necessarily sharing with other people.

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated here. It's asking about folders on the hard drive, not anything to do with the web interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to have a folder synchronized without having the location of the folder within your Google Drive folder, you can do so with [Symlinks](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/). The program mentioned in that article, Link Shell Extension, is a great way to do this if you're either uncomfortable with the command line, or if you're doing most of your folder operations in explorer.

Comment: There's a serious caveat. "Symbolic Links" and "Hard Links" are way cool.  However, I concluded I might not be smart enough to safely use it.  If you don't know and watch what you are doing, you can LOSE data.  For instance, this came from the Symlinks site listed above:

""Caution: Make sure to never create a symbolic link inside of a symbolic link. For instance, don’t create a symbolic link to a file that’s contained in a symbolic linked folder. This can create a loop, which can cause millions of problems you don’t want to deal with. Seriously.""

Comment: I think this means:  Don't add a folder or file to the Google Drive folder, if THAT folder is already a symbolic link.  Theoretically, you could already have your local Google Drive folder inside a symbolic link, like "My Documents".

Comment: @DaaBoss This is unlikely to happen intentionally, and there's no logical reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can share any folder in Google Drive via:

- Navigate to folder (don't go inside)
- Right click > Share > Share

Example image below:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, why was this downvoted? It may not be the answer they picked but I don't see what's wrong with it in and of itself.

Comment: It seems to not answer the question which, admittedly, uses the word "share" in a different way than most people would use it.